# How to print the page after user input?

Tags: javascript, printing

I am trying to print a partial page using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
        var divContents = $("#PrintContent").html();
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>My Print Title</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
        printWindow.document.write(divContents);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
    });
</script>
```

Everything is fine but when a user changed some input (a form inside the print div), such as after clicking the checkbox, the print window still shows the original page (empty form or the initial value).  How can I let the user print the page with his input?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `.live()`? It's been deprecated for years now. Also, why not simlpy use a proper `media=print` CSS so the user can print the actual page properly?

Comment: It would be more clear if you create a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Jsfiddle.net does not allow me to use the document.write. I will try css print. Thanks all.

Comment: Try also my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A state of a form is kept in the DOM, not HTML. When calling jQuery's `html()` function you loose your values. Instead, you have to clone the whole jQuery object and attach it to the new window.

```
$("#btnPrint").on("click", function () {
  var divContents = $("#PrintContent").clone();
  var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');

  divContents.appendTo(printWindow.document.body);
  printWindow.print();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NameFILIP/up6p0zk5/